# Uninstall MS Teams

Tags: uninstall, microsoft-teams

I had a problem with the MS Teams app and tried to update my version via the package manager. This however led to an additional installation of MS Teams. I wanted to uninstall both applications now to clear my system.

Using `sudo apt remove teams` I was able to uninstall one of the installations. The other one is still being shown when I view the application screen, and I don't know how to remove it.

Comment: I recommend considering also [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391091/reinstall-ms-teams-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-21-10/1391092#1391092) on how to manually uninstall MS Teams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have installed the other one as a snap package, as Ubuntu's new software store defaults to snap packages.

Open a terminal and enter the command

```
sudo snap remove teams
```

There are three packages for Teams in the snap store. If the first command did not work, you may also try the following commands one by one.

```
sudo snap remove teams-insiders
```

and,

```
sudo snap remove teams-for-linux
```