# Reinstall MS teams after upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: apt, dpkg, uninstall, snap, microsoft-teams

I had MS Teams Preview running (mostly) smoothly on Ubuntu 20.04.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10 at first, Teams pretended to work flawlessly, but after some time, different issues occurred.

For example,

I) when I wanted to share my screen in a call, the toolbar with the screen selection was empty (with no error message).

II) The microphone stopped working randomly, followed by an error message popping up saying that the microphone stopped working. It happened independent of using a Bluetooth headset or the system microphone.

I tried to reinstall Teams, but the package couldn't be located by any of `apt`, `dpkg` or `snap`.
There were no entries related to MS teams in

```
dpkg -l | grep teams
```

and

```
apt list | grep teams
```

Since no package manager could find MS Teams, the suggested steps to [remove MS Teams](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362161/uninstall-ms-teams), [permanently uninstall MS Teams](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219523/how-to-permanently-uninstall-microsoft-teams) or to [delete a package completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package) did not work.

Answer (score 5):

MS Teams could be installed successfully after manually removing MS Teams on Ubuntu 21.10 with the following steps:

**0. Make sure teams is not running in the background**

Quit the application.

**1. Manually remove all MS Teams directories**

```
rm -r ~/.config/Microsoft/
rm -r ~/.config/'Microsoft Teams - Preview'/
rm -r ~/.config/teams/
rm -r ~/.config/'teams (deleted)'/

rm -r /usr/share/teams/

rm /usr/bin/teams
```

**2. Install MS Teams**

Taken from [this guide](https://pureinfotech.com/install-microsoft-teams-linux/).

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list'

sudo apt update
sudo apt install teams
```

As I didn't find a related post to remove MS Teams on Ubuntu manually, I hope sharing my experience will help someone else out there in the future.

**Edit:** The empty sharing tray issue is persisting and caused by MS Teams' lack of support for Wayland (see [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/408938/sharing-tray-emptyblankblack-in-teams-on-ubuntu-21.html)).